# dofactory for .NET 4.5

Tags: .net

I ran across this product today,
http://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns
and I found a thread here about it, but it is extremely out of date. Has anyone used dofactory 4.5 as a learning aid? If so, what was your experience level prior to using it and how did it help/hinder your progress as a .NET developer? What was your impression of their RAD tool Spark?

It looks very interesting and seems to provide a ton of material.

Thank you for your response.

Comment: I have not used dofactory but the home page is covered with information about the Gang-of-Four Design patterns.  These patterns are timeless in my opinion and learning about them is a great idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation of patterns varies as new constructs are introduced to a language.  Quite often constructs or class libraries are introduced specifically to accommodate well known design patterns.

It's more important to understand the concepts, and recognize that the GOF patterns are taking common computing problems and creating abstract solutions to these problems.  How you implement the solution using a GOF pattern can vary widely on what's available in the language and what third party libraries you use.  e.g. If you were using NInject you probably wouldn't be coding anything that implements the Abstract Factory or the Singleton pattern as these can be easily achieved using NInject.

I'm very familiar with dofactory and I think the content on their site is excellent for anyone learning C# and/or GOF patterns.  I'm NOT familiar with their RAD tool Spark, I had a very quick look, it seems like it provides content similiar to their web site, just in much greater depth, although I could be totally wrong.